# Is the duration of usage no longer publicised?

Tags: support

It seems to me that I can no longer see how long a User has been on a particular website on the Stack Exchange platform.

Possibly this is a matter of GDPR, a matter of 'identifying' individuals, which I would quite understand.

Is this the case ?

Comment: Do you mean the info saying when they registered, how many days they've been active etc? I can see it as a mod, but on other sites I see that it's missing. That is odd. I agree, it is helpful info.

Comment: Sounds like it disappeared yesterday: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/256282

Answer (score 3):

The company decided to make changes to the profile page without seeking any input from any community members.  The post announcing the changes is now the 10th most downvoted post on Meta.SE

[Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive)

You can decide for yourself if the stated resaons for the changes are reasonable - feel free to vote!